# PostgreSQL: Deleting foreign server in a function will not work if the next statement is RAISE EXCEPTION

Tags: postgresql, exception, postgresql-9.6

In PostgreSQL 9.6.

I have a function where I create a temporary foreign server. I use it and then I try to delete it.

BUT, when I try to throw an exception immediately after the delete server call, the server does not get deleted. If I comment out the raise exception then the foreign server gets deleted.

Doing this, the foreign server **is not** deleted:

```
if (errcondition=true) then
    func_delete_server(srv_name);

    raise exception '%', 'an error happened';
end if;
```

Doing this, the foreign server **is** deleted

```
if (errcondition=true) then
    func_delete_server(srv_name);

    --raise exception '%', 'an error happened';
end if;
```

`func_delete_server` simply contains a `drop server` statement.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems like the transaction never gets completed due to the exception being raised. If  an exception is raised from the deletion, why not use the exception that was from that line in place of `'an error happened'`?

Comment: When you call ```raise exception``` , anything on that session will be rollback so nothing gets committed which in you case is ```DELETE```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case `raise exception` is not the a good way to notify the consumer who is calling this function.

Firing an Exception (`raise exception`) is not a good way, where you want some job to be done before you notify and it's agains the Transaction rule.

You simply need to call `RETURN` to terminate the function or have some boolean variables within the your RETURN.

Basically its all depend on how you have declare you function.